# Create divs in html file or javascript file

Tags: jquery, html

I was wondering, what's more viable between the following two options...

- Create hiddens divs in a html file and show them with JQuery (a pop-up, for example...)
- Or Create the div in the javascript file and call it whenever you want to use it; without creating all the hidden divs in the diferents html files you want it to be displayed...

Comment: I always create them dynamically with document.createElement('elemname'). That way I can couple references to the dom objects directly without having to do expensive lookups with $('lskdjl') or document.getElementById.

Comment: If you use later option, anyway you are creating a div and when not required you'll be removing it or hiding. Then, why not go for 1st option.

Comment: There is no correct answer. There are other considerations not mentioned in your question also. Therefore question is off topic as opinion based

Comment: The answer may vary from one case to another case, as far as I knew, you should always separate the HTML and JS. I prefer to put the hidden div in the HTML, JS only need to handle the behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion it depends. If you're trying to create a simple sort of message, for examaple:

```
<div class="alert">
   Error occured
</div>
```

..then it's probably OK to create it in the JS code. Instead of having the same HTML code on every page, you could have a simple code such as:

```
$(document).append('<div class="alert">' + someMsg + '</div>');
```

..and only once. But with more complicated stuff such as a dialog that contains several fields and some logic behind I would probably go with html being already on the page. Since the HTML needs to be there anyway and maintaining it all in JS tend to be a bit more messy. Also, you can put such HTML only to pages where you really need it.

It also depends on your popup dialogs - are they modal dialog (always one at a time) or non-modal and user can theoretically open many of them at the same time? If it does you'll probably need to create them anyway and clone the same exact HTML. In this case you could have sort of HTML template on the page and control just the logic in JS (e.g. calculated content etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than show and hide the divs I would add them where needed. This way you are not sending the same data multiple times. If you are using jQuery then building these divs is quick and easy like this:

```
jQuery('<div/>', {
    id: 'divId',
    class: 'divClass'

}).appendTo('#mySelector');
```

Otherwise you can create elements using the createElement function:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp

Comment: Yes, but we're talking about a well-built div; a pop-up for example, as I said before. You will need multiple divs, inputs, maybe a form... it won't be only one div...

Answer (score 0):

> call it whenever you want to use it

Since you write this in your question, I am going to assume you are planning to use it more then once within your application or website.

I would recommend using the javascript option. It is better for reuseability and if you ever want to change it, you only have to do it in one place.